# Array property in Phing

Tags: php, phing

I have a phing build file that checks the permission of certain files using the     <touch> task.

```
<target description="list of files to check permission" name="files-to-test">
    <property name="filesToCheck" value=""/>
    <php expression="file_get_contents('filesToCheck.txt')" returnProperty="filesToCheck"/>
    <foreach list="${filesToCheck}" param="file" target="permission-test"/>
</target>

<target description="Test the permission of files that needs to be written" name="permission-test">
    <touch file="${file}"/>
</target>
```

It calls an extenal file(filesToCheck.txt) which is just a list of different file locations. This works fine. But it prevents me from reusing the same list in my PHP code when I want to access a particular file based on a certain key from the same external file(filesToCheck.txt).

I looked through Phing's documentation but didn't find any array Task. Does anyone know of a work around or is creating a new task the only solution for handling an array property in Phing ?

Answer (score 3):

I ended up creating an ad-hoc task because the touch task wasn't the most efficient way of checking for file permissions. PHP's [touch](http://il.php.net/manual/en/function.touch.php#86781) doesn't work as expected for files if the user is not the owner of the file.

This is the ad-hoc task I came up with:

```
           <adhoc-task name="is-file-writeable">
            <![CDATA[

            class IsFileWriteableTest extends Task 
            {
                private $file;

                           function setFile($file) 
                {
                    $filesArray = parse_ini_file('filesToCheck.ini');
                    $this->files = $filesArray;
                }

                function main() 
                {
                    foreach ($this->files as $fileName => $fileLocation)    
                    {
                        if (!is_writable($fileLocation)) 
                        {    
                            throw new Exception("No write permission for $fileLocation");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            ]]>
            </adhoc-task>

            <target description="list of files to check permission" name="files-to-test">
            <is-file-writeable file="/path/to/filesToCheck.ini" />
            </target>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could probably just create an ad-hoc task as a quick-n-dirty solution, or your own task to be a bit more robust about it.  I've used Phing for a while myself and nothing jumps out at me as an alternative to writing it yourself.